# I would like to understand each line how this code removes duplicates in a list , so this is the list (a b a a a c c) gives (a b)

Tags: scheme, lisp

here is the code and its working fine on scheme lisp

```
(define (rdup ls)
  (let loop ((ls ls) (current #f))
    (cond ((null? ls)               ())
          ((null? (cdr ls))         (if (eq? (car ls) current) () ls))
          ((eq? (car ls) (cadr ls)) (loop (cdr ls) (car ls)))
          ((eq? (car ls) current)   (loop (cdr ls) current))
          (else                     (cons (car ls) (loop (cdr ls) (car ls)))) )))
```

and here is what i tried

```
(rdup '(a b a a a c c))
```

and got `(a b)`

I want to know how each line of the code works

Comment: I would start be posting code which is better formatted. Could you please improve the indentation and formatting of the code? Thank you.

Comment: hope its better now :)

Comment: Not really. The LET form should be indented. The IF form, too. The second NULL? form should be on its own line. The last line should be indented. The editor should actually help with that. Can you improve that? Correctly indented code is necessary, otherwise the code gets harder to read and understand.

Comment: It looks like the variable `loop` is a predicate on several terms with this indentation. `() ` is not a valid scheme expression so the second term will fail.

Comment: Aw noo no , loop is not a variable, it literally loops, it is supposed to be blue here, but it loops through the list and it does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added line numbers and fixed your indentation to make it easier to explain:

```
01 (define (rdup ls)
02 (let loop ((ls ls)
03 (current #f))  
04  (cond
05   ((null? ls) '())
06   ((null? (cdr ls)) 
07        (if (eq? (car ls) current) '() ls))
08   ((eq? (car ls) (cadr ls)) 
09        (loop (cdr ls) (car ls)))
10   ((eq? (car ls) current) 
11        (loop (cdr ls) current))
12   (else (cons (car ls) 
13        (loop (cdr ls) (car ls)))))))
```

Line 02: You are using a special form of the let syntax to create a named procedure that you can then call from within the let. You are defining (confusingly) a variable inside the loop `ls` with the exact same name as a variable outside of the loop, giving the internal variable the initial value of the external one. You are also defining a second parameter, `current` that you are giving the initial value of `#f`.

Line 04 starts a `cond`.

Line 05 (I corrected it so it would work by quoting the empty list) returns an empty list if `ls` is null. This stops the procedure and unwinds the stack.

Line 06 checks if the `cdr` is null, indicating that you are operating on the last element of the list. If that is true, you go to line 07 and either return an empty list if the `car` of `ls` is equal to `current`, or you return `ls`. This also ends the procedure and unwinds the stack.

Lines 08-09 look for duplicates in a row and if so it calls the loop procedure using the `cdr` as the new list and the `car` as the `current`.

Lines 10-11 check if the `car` is equal to `current` and if so it calls the loop procedure with the `cdr` (again iterating down the list) and `current`.

If none of those conditions are met, lines 12-13 will create a new list by `cons`-ing the `car` of `ls` with the result of calling the `let`-created `loop` procedure on the `cdr` of `ls` and the `car` of `ls`.

If the procedure worked as intended, it should have returned `'(a b c)`.

Here's one that works as I think your program is intended to work:

```
(define rdup
  (lambda (l)
   (reverse (let loop ((lst l)
               (c '()))
      (cond
        ((null? lst) c)
        (else
         (if (member (car lst) c)
             (loop (cdr lst) c)
             (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) c)))))))))
```

Comment: @ querist a better way to say what i need is that "eliminate all subsequences of two or more repeated elements"